# set state to buttons by default

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have two text views whose background image I want to change.

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_padding_2dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_5dp"
            android:text="Trainings"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
            android:clickable="true"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/learning_programs"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Learning Programs"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_5dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_seventeen"
            android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            />
```

So, what I want is that when I click on a TextView the background image should change. For that, I have a selector in drawable as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner" android:state_focused="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner_grey"/>
</selector>
```

But the problem with the above code is that it retains the white color only when the user taps on the TextView. Once the finger of the user moves, the color changes to grey.

What I want is that the color should become white after the user has clicked on the TextView once.

With `state_selected:true` both the TextViews become white and non-clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line of code to both textviews.

android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

This means that the view can get the focus when the phone is in touch mode.

**EDIT**:
Try this xml and check if it works.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_padding_2dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_5dp"
    android:text="Trainings"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/learning_programs"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_5dp"
    android:text="Learning Programs"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_seventeen" />
```

Comment: It should work.I have copied your code to my studio and have checked dude.

Comment: No it isn't. I am also trying the same thing.

Comment: try adding  android:focusable="true" and let me know,anyhow for me its working..in emulator 8.0

Comment: you are using the xml and selector which you provide above no?don’t make any  changes to that.Its perfect.What happens when you click on text view?

Comment: It becomes white and when I untap it , it becomes grey again. What i want is that the white color should retain after it is tapped once

Comment: is there something as setCancelable(false) for this thing?

Answer (score 1):

When your finger release from the view, your view is not in `selected` or `pressed` state. You need to set the `pressed` or `selected` state manually after click event.

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/sample_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
```

Then in your code

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setSelected(!v.isSelected());
    }
});
```

You can use one `OnClickListener` for two `TextView`

```
private View.OnClickListener toggleSelectedStateOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setSelected(!v.isSelected());
    }
};

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
tv.setOnClickListener(toggleSelectedStateOnClickListener);

TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setOnClickListener(toggleSelectedStateOnClickListener);
```

Comment: I have two TextViews, how do I make this generalised?

Comment: by this code, I can select both the textViews at one time. Is there a way to select one at a time,such that if I select the other way, the first one automatically gets deselected?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i use this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:color="@color/bottom_nav_normal" android:state_enabled="true"/>
        <item android:color="@color/bottom_nav_checked" android:state_enabled="false"/>
        <item android:color="@color/bottom_nav_checked" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    </selector>
```

then, in the code:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO
            tv.setEnable(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think u should code a custom view is more effective